# Matlab : (.)^*T operation for complex numbers

Tags: matlab, matrix, transpose, complex-numbers

The answer to the question asked here [Why is complex conjugate transpose the default in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28104040/why-is-complex-conjugate-transpose-the-default-in-matlab?rq=1)

says that for complex numbers we can use `'` symbol to denote the transpose operation that is used for real numbers. Mathematically, the transpose operation that is done for real valued numbers is denoted by the symbol  `(.)^T` . For the transpose of complex numbers the equivalent symbol is `(.)^H`. The way it is done is -- First we take the conjugate of the complex number and then take its transpose. This is the operation `(.)^H`.

I want to implement the operation `(.)^{*T} = (.)^H` for complex number. I have used the symbol apostrophe for this. Please correct me where wrong.

I wanted to confirm if my implementation of the concept is correct or not using Matlab. For example, for real valued vector `A_r`, I want to multiply it with its transpose `multiply_r = A_r*A_r'`

Replicating the same for complex valued vector `A_c`, this operation would become `multiply_c = A_c * A_c'`

```
A_r =[1,2,3]; %real valued vector
B_r = A_r'; %transpose of real valued vector
multiply_r =A_r*B_r;

A_c = [1 + sqrt(-1)*1, 2+sqrt(-1)*2, 3+sqrt(-1)*3]; %complex valued vector
B_c = A_c'; %transpose of complex valued vector
multiply_c = A_c*B_c;
```

Is this okay?

UPDATE : I am trying to take the normal transpose of this complex valued array, so that it is arranged in 3 rows and 1 column intead of 1 row and 3 columns. Using the operator `.'` I am getting weird values because the array is now increased in size !! What is the proper way?

```
h = [ -5.1053 + 3.6797i  1.3327 + 5.7339i  4.1302 -10.7521i].'

h =

  -5.1053 + 3.6797i
   1.3327 + 5.7339i
   4.1302          
        0 -10.7521i
```

Comment: Looks godd. But it depends on what you want to do. If for complex numbers you want transpose (without conjugate) use `.'`. If you want conjugate transpose use `'`

Comment: @Luis Mendo: I want to do the operation equivalent to $(.)^{*T} = (.)^H$ . Then what should I use? Is this conjugate transpose?

Comment: BTW, you don;t need to write `sqrt(-1)` you have `i` and `j` symbols for this in Matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, Matlab has both matrix "transpose" (`(.)^T`) and "conjugate transpose" (`(.)^H`) defined.
For real-valued transpose, you have [`transpose`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html), that can be expressed as an operator `.'` (note the '.' before the `'`):

```
aT = transpose(a);
isequal( aT, a.' );  % transpose() and .' are the same
```

For complex conjugate transpose you have [`ctranspose`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conj.html), that can be expressed as an operator `'` (note there is **no** `.` before the `'`):

```
aH = ctranspose(a);
isequal( aH, a' );  % ctranspose and ' are the same
```

You can verify using [`conj`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conj.html):

```
isequal( a', conj(a).' );
```

Comment: Could you please see the update in my question? I am having a weird situation when uing the operator for a particular case

Comment: @SKM use commas to separate values

Comment: These values are generated by the program during run-time using an equation, I cannot put comma. Is there a way by which once the equation computes these values, I can put a comma?

Comment: @SKM can you eliminate spaces?

Comment: No, I am afraid no modification can be done because these are generated from an estimator :(

Comment: I did a hack and solved the problem by initialiizing the vector as row order.