# matlab accumarray with complex numbers

Tags: matlab, complex-numbers

I don't understand `accumarray` behaviour when passed complex numbers. I expect `accumarray([1 1]', [1i 2i]')` to behave like `sum([1i 2i])` (for this particuar case).

It however returns `0.0000 - 3.0000i` instead of `0.0000 + 3.0000i`.

Comment: Related: [Why is complex conjugate transpose the default in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28104040/3978545)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mixed up your operators. `'`  is the **complex conjugate transpose**. Use `.'` to do a regular transpose. So you're doing `sum([-1i; -2i])` which is indeed `-3i`. Calling `accumarray([1 1].', [1i 2i].')`, mind the dots, gives `0.0000 + 3.0000i`.

See also [Why is complex conjugate transpose the default in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28104040)